Ubuntu 24.04 mouse and keyboard not working on login screen
When the login screen appears on my server I cannot sign in because the mouse and keyboard do not work. They do work if I go into recovery mode and during the initial boot prior to the login screen. IPMI/BMC has the same issue.
I tried following the instructions here by booting into recovery mode;
however, I run into several issues with the sudo apt-get update.
A bunch of "failure to fetch ..." error messages
Eg "temporarily failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com' 'security.ubuntu.com', etc.
Here is a screenshot of the login screen where my mouse/keyboard doesn't work.

Here is screenshot of output when I run sudo apt update

Edit: video card model is:
VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 41)

Sounds like a video driver, issue, probably incompletely installed or totally missing driver.  Add your video card model to the question.

I edited the question to include the video card model.
